# Why does OpenCV's SetData not actually set the image data?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I have a program using OpenCV 2 to do marker detection in an image (written in C, with a Python 2 ctypes wrapper), and I'm trying to get the output from a Raspberry Pi camera into that code.

Essentially, I have a 2D numpy array `image` with the greyscale image data in (from `cv2.imdecode`); I then do this to get an empty `IplImage`:

```py
ipl_image = cv2.cv.CreateImageHeader((image.shape[1], image.shape[0]), cv2.cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1)
```

and then assign the actual image data to the `IplImage` like this:

```py
cv2.cv.SetData(ipl_image, image.tobytes(), image.dtype.itemsize * image.shape[1])
```

If I then call the image-analysing function (`find_markers_fp`), I get a segfault – through much printf debugging, I found out that the `IplImage->imageData` is 0, when it should be a pointer to the image data, despite the fact that I called `SetData`. This causes the C program to try to do a null pointer dereference, hence the segfault.

Somehow, I figured out that calling `ipl_image.tostring()` before I call `find_markers_fp` will make it work, but this function isn't documented anywhere in the [OpenCV 2.4 documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13.2/index.html), only in the [version 2.1 documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20100620104336/http://opencv.willowgarage.com:80/documentation/python/basic_structures.html#iplimage). I don't do anything with the result of the function, I just call it, and the C program starts returning valid results rather than segfaulting.

Why does calling this function make the `IplImage` usable, or more importantly, how can I avoid using this undocumented function?

Comment: Don't use obsolete C api.

Comment: @Miki How should I get an `IplImage` then? Or is the whole `IplImage` data structure obsolete?

Comment: the whole IplImage data structure obsolete